# How do I allow one of the two inputs from a user to match the regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have two different regular expressions for zipcodes from two different countries. One being The Netherlands and the other one being Belgium.

The Netherlands:

```
.match(/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[A-Za-z]{2}$/g)
```

Belgium:

```
.match(/^[1-9]{1}\d{3}$/g)
```

The user can input either a dutch zipcode or a belgium zipcode. So for example the user can input: 1111 AA (Netherlands) or 1111 (Belgium). However I want regex to allow one of the two inputs, but I just can't get it to work

This is what I have tried so far:

```
.match(/^(?:[1-9]{1}\d{3}) | ([1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[A-Za-z]{2}$)/g)
```

But it just messes up the whole regex and doesn't allow any of the 2 zipcodes. Am I misusing the OR operator?

Comment: Spaces between `|` are *meaningful*. See `/^(?:[1-9]\d{3}|[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[A-Za-z]{2})$/` https://regex101.com/r/1hnTGX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have mistakenly put a leading/trailing space character around the alternation. However, it seems you can remove the alternation alltogether and use an optional non-capture group:

```
^[1-9]\d{3}(?: ?(?!s[ads])[A-Z]{2})?$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hTagi8/1)

---

- `^` - Start line anchor;
- `[1-9]\d{3}` - A digit ranging 1-9 followed by another three digits;
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group;

  - `?(?!s[ads])` - An optional space followed by an negative lookahead to assert position isn't followed by any combination of an 's' with 'ads';
  - `[A-Z]{2}` - Two alpa-chars;
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

---

Note that I matched this case-insensitive.